# azure mobile services authentication

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application for Windows Phone 8. I am trying to implement authentication using this very simple example here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-wp8/, followed by this one here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/authorize-users-in-scripts-wp8/. It is essential for my application to continue to be able authenticate and control access of the users of my application. Specifically my problem is here:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Authenticate()
{
    while (user == null)
    {
        string message;
        try
        {
            user = await App.MobileService
                        .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
            message = string.Format("You are now logged in - {0}", user.UserId);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            message = e + "You must log in. Login Required";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

This is about as much code as there is for both tutorials. It starts the login screen at `user = await App.MobileService
                        .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);`
but after accepting the login credentials, it starts displaying the error message which is:

```
+       $exception  {System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start a login operation because login is already in progress.

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.<SendLoginAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
at SeeThrough.MainPage.<Authenticate>d__7.MoveNext()}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

It repeats this process because "user" never gets assigned, due to the "login is already in progress" situation. I cant find anything online to help, I have searched for this error and only get 4 hits of the exact problem which are bits of github code and no help as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not configured the account properly. Please provide the right Mobile service URL in the App registration page in live dashboard. If the URL is not right it is more likely to get such exceptions !

Comment: the redirect url in live connect developer center is identicle as the  MOBILE SERVICE URL displayed in azure managment portal. the client id and client secret are also ideticle in both. Does the client id have to be in the application it self some where maybe this is for my final project at uni it going to make me fail if its not sorted soon

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this helped me.

Quoting answer from [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/95c6569e-2fa2-43c8-af71-939e006a9b27/mobile-services-loginasync-remote-procedure-call-failed-hresult-0x800706be?forum=azuremobile)

> I forgot to mention, that our tutorials are not yet updated for window
>   phone 8.1, so you will also need to add the following code as well
>   into your app.xaml.cs (this snippet is for a univeral app, phone 8.1
>   would be the same just without needing it to be conditional)

```cs
protected override void OnActivated (IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated (args);

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation)
        App.<mobileservice>.LoginComplete (args as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
#endif
}
```